# CSS text-align:justify chrome overflows

Tags: css

When using `text-align: justify;` to justify a text chromes lets some of the lines overflow the parent div (in my case `p`). While other browsers (I tested it on Mozilla Firefox only), seem to be working fine with this property.

Here is an image to elaborate the issue:

[image: CSS text justify chrome issue]

And here is [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Emad_Omar/5myjg3we/) contains a simple code of mine

Please note that I'm using:

- Bootstrap 3.2.0
- [bootstrap-rtl-3.2.0-rc4](https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I apologize, I accidentally posted the question before I complete it.

Comment: I tried your fiddle. I added "text-align:justify" to the <p> element and it justified properly for me in Chrome, both left and right. I'm on a Mac Book running Chrome Version 36.0.1985.125.

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell I apologize again, I forgot to include the custom css.. Now I just updated the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Emad_Omar/5myjg3we/5/embedded/result/).. Please try to resize the html frame or the browser window.. as I notice this issue seems to appear with some texts and depend on the width of the container.. Also, I noticed that if I pressed the `TidyUp` button in the jsfiddle the issue will surprisingly disapper!! Do you have an explanation for this too?

Comment: @Abdo: have you added bootstrap-responsive.css yet??

Answer (score 4):

### Futures Search - Works Fine!

```
text-align: justify;
display: table-row;
text-align-last: justify;
```

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjs7A.png)

Answer (score 1):

adding `display:inline;` to `#product-description p`

```
#product-description p {
  text-align: justify;
  display:inline;/*added*/
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/53Ljf4rm/embedded/result/)

Or add `display:inline;` to `#product-description`

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/53Ljf4rm/1/embedded/result/)

Added `display: inline;` to `.panel-body` working well as i can see for both browser:

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/53Ljf4rm/2/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
word-break: break-word;
```

into your class

Comment: Breaking words a rbitraril y is not acceptable for many writing systems, including Latin and Arabic.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's very late to answer this question but

> text-align: justify;

Doesn't work on chrome. You can check [here](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-text-justify)